# Getting past security answer using PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl, authentication

This script gets through the main login form, but does not post at the security question screen. Any help? The result just prints out the security question screen, even though I am trying to make it POST.

```
    $username = 'XXXX';
    $password = 'XXXX';
    $loginUrl = 'https://www.dandh.ca/v4/dh';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'Login='.urlencode($username).'&PW='.urlencode($password).'&Request=Login&formName=Login&jsEnabled=0&queryString=&Platform=Full&btLogin='.urlencode('Log In'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "my_cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "my_cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36");

    curl_exec($ch);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'securityAnswer=XXXX&Request=postForm&formName=loginChallengeValidation&btContinue=Continue');

    echo curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: `Curl_error()` might help finding out what goes wrong

Comment: https://www.dandh.ca/v4/dh is down

Comment: curl_error() shows no error.

Comment: dandh.ca/v4/dh is the form post location in the source code of the webpage.

Comment: Are you doing `echo curl_error($ch)`?

Comment: I fixed the blank page, it was because I was encoding the URL curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, urlencode($loginUrl));

Now I am at a page asking for security answer, and I am trying to automate this screen now.

Comment: I've updated the original post.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you don't have a cert file. You could set option CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to FALSE.

Comment: I've updated the original post. I need help at the security question screen. It won't post.

Comment: @user2489314 You are sending two requests, so you probably need to set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);` - it will remember session cookies between requests.